# Gatsby.js adding a global function to checkUserSession

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux, gatsby

I am wondering how to set a global function to be rendered in all gatsby pages, by using create-react-app I used to do that in the App.js file,but now I don't know how to manipulate it with using Gatsby
this is what I want to implement :

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(()=>{
  dispatch(checkUserSession())
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the multiple Gatsby Browser APIs. In your case, [`onRouteUpdate`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onRouteUpdate) should do the trick. Add in the `gatsby-browser.js` the following:

```
exports.onRouteUpdate = () => {
  checkUserSession()
}
```

`onRouteUpdate` is called when the user changes routes, including on the initial load of the app

Comment: Thank you , another question please , how can I define react hook useDispatch inside `gatsby-browser.js`

Comment: I get this error :`React Hook "useDispatch" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React       
function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`